# How to correctly dockerize and continuously integrate 20GB raw data?

Tags: performance, docker, continuous-integration

I have an application that uses about 20GB of raw data. The raw data consists of binaries.

The files rarely - if ever - change. Changes only happen if there are errors within the files that need to be resolved.

The most simple way to handle this would be to put the files in its own git repository and create a base image based on that. Then build the application on top of the raw data image. 
Having a 20GB base image for a CI pipeline is not something I have tried and does not seem to be the optimal way to handle this situation.

The main reason for my approach here ist to prevent extra deployment complexity.

Is there a best practice, "correct" or more sensible way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Huge mostly-static data blocks like this are probably the one big exception to me to the “Docker images should be self-contained” rule.  I’d suggest keeping this data somewhere else, and download it separately from the core `docker run` workflow.

I have had trouble in the past with multi-gigabyte images.  Operations like `docker push` and `docker pull` in particular are prone to hanging up on the second gigabyte of individual layers.  If, as you say, this static content changes rarely, there’s also a question of where to put it in the linear sequence of layers.  It’s tempting to write something like

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ADD really-big-content.tar.gz /data
...
```

But even the `ubuntu:18.04` image changes regularly (it gets security updates fairly frequently; your CI pipeline should explicitly `docker pull` it) and when it does a new build will have to transfer this entire unchanged 20 GB block again.

Instead I would put them somewhere like an AWS S3 bucket or similar object storage.  (This is a poor match for source control systems, which (a) want to keep old content forever and (b) tend to be optimized for text rather than binary files.). Then I’d have a script that runs on the host that downloads that content, and then mount the corresponding host directory into the containers that need it.

```
curl -LO http://downloads.example.com/really-big-content.tar.gz
tar xzf really-big-content.tar.gz
docker run -v $PWD/really-big-content:/data ...
```

(In Kubernetes or another distributed world, I’d probably need to write a dedicated Job to download the content into a Persistent Volume and run that as part of my cluster bring-up.  You could do the same thing in plain Docker to download the content into a named volume.)

Comment: Agree with @David answer, I have experienced the same with WordPress site during docker pull.

Comment: good answer! what about using git for the mounted volume for deployment?

Comment: So `git clone` will intrinsically download all of history to your local system (as will Subversion, Mercurial, and anything else from this millennium); so that will double your disk usage _now_, and as your files change over time the size of history will keep growing.  That’s why I suggest not using Git here.  But beyond that, it will work fine.